# abrir winword.exe desde python con el modulo OS

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas noches quisiera saber como puedo ejecutar un comando de MS-DOS desde python.

Necesito abrir WINWORD.EXE y este es el codigo que utilizo

```
import os
r = os.system("C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/")
T = r + os.system("/WINWORD.EXE")
```

pero no funciona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casi lo tienes, debiera ser algo así:

```
import os
r = os.system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE")
```

Consideraciones:

- Según la documentación [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system): `Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.`, es decir que el comando se debe indicar con el path completo en el parámetro (le estabas pasando solo la ruta)
- Toma nota además que estamos usando las barras "naturales" de Windows `\`, pero en este caso es necesario escaparlas agregando una doble barra `\\`, sino una forma muy útil y compatible entre sistemas es construir la ruta completa medianter [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: como puedo indicarle que imprima un archvio desde la linea de comando. a una impreosa usb , algo como esto: AcroRd32.exe /t "C:\test.pdf" "\\servername\printername"

Comment: Por linea de comando me da la impresión que no se puede ya que Word no pareciera que implemente algún comando de impresión: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6